# String pattern for checking the first 8 characters are same in luci

Tags: regex, string, lua, openwrt, luci

I am using Luci-Lua in openWRT. I need a function to validate the password field that only accepts alphanumeric and the first 8 characters are not same. Please check my code and help me.

```
function pw1.validate(self, value)
  if #value <= 6 and not value:find('^[%-%.%w]+$') then
    return nil
  end

  if value:match("^(.)\1*$") then
     return nil
  end

  return value
end
```

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `value:match("^(.)\1*$")` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The central point of your question is: The pinnacle of your question is

> the first 8 characters are not same

As suggested, this can be done with a Lua pattern (similar to a regex).
If you want to check if the first 8 characters are all the same you could use

```
function validate1st8NotSame(value)
    if value:match("^(.)%1%1%1%1%1%1%1") then
      return false
    end
    return true
end

print(validate1st8NotSame("aaaaaaaa")) --not valid
print(validate1st8NotSame("aaaaaaab")) --valid
print(validate1st8NotSame("aaaaaaa")) --!?
```

The pattern works like this:

- `^(.)` capture the character at position 1,
- `%1%1%1%1%1%1%1` use a back reference `%1` to it to check the capture repeats 8 times.

If you actually want to check whether the first 8 characters do not contain an identical character then a bit more complicated pattern is needed:

```
function validate1st8NoSame(value)
    if value:sub(1,8):match("(.).-%1") then
         return false
    end
    return true
end

print(validate1st8NoSame("abcdefghe")) --valid
print(validate1st8NoSame("abcdefgae")) --invalid
```

The idea here is:

- `value:sub(1,8)` get the first 8 characters
- `(.)` capture a single char
- `.-` matches the shortest possible sequence of 0 or more repetitions of any characters ;
- `%1` backreference to the captured character

The following regex [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sSYdY0/1) that applies the same logic hopefully makes is more tangible.

[**Sample Code**](https://ideone.com/vlSTKV)